# Is there something like a virtual VPN?

Tags: security, vpn

I am a small business owner, an ecommerce company, faced with following problem.

Current situation. We have an office with a physical location. The office has a Cisco ASA Firewall / Router to connect to the outside world. The router is configured for VPN as well. Some remote workers, log in to the VPN to access some local network resources, etc. I also use the VPN and internal IP of our office to secure many other things. For example, we have off-site production servers. RDP and FTP access to those servers is limited to people that are physically in the office or VPN'ed in the office. Based on the IP of the office.

We are looking to go virtual and have no more office. The local network resources would be moved to something like AWS. However, I can't figure out how to secure my production web server anymore. I really liked the fact that RDP and FTP were restricted to only one IP address. If I don't have a physical location anymore, I would loose that IP address.

That is why I was wondering if there was such a service as a 'virtual vpn' where remote workers could log in to and be authenticated.

Comment: Why are you using FTP in this day and age, for anything other than public access? (And I would say that it's doubtful even for public access, unless you've got something like apt's automatic validation of cryptographic signatures.)

Comment: What's wrong with setting up a VPN on the production server itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I don't have a physical location anymore, I would loose that IP
>   address.

Yes, but that doesn't mean you're out of luck.

It would be relatively simple for you to configure a very similar setup to what you currently have, only in AWS. This is something I've done many, many times.

Stand up a VPN server (OpenVPN on Linux is what I would recommend for this use case) in an AWS VPC, give it an Elastic IP address, and then limit access to your production environment to requests that come from that IP.

Comment: How many concurrent users could be supported with this approach?